# How to load only used classes of CSS files in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've got a question about loading CSS files,
Is there any way or method to optimize the loading procedure by cutting back on classes that are not used in the current page and load the ones that are being used currently in ASP.NET MVC?
As an example suppose that the current page has style.css linked to it, style.css has 230 different classes defined, but the current page only uses 5 . Is there any way to make it load only those 5 classes and send a somehow customized version of style.css not the whole file?

Comment: Bundling and minification should at least reduce the size.

Comment: Are your pages entirely static (no javascript)? If not, what happens if JS adds a new class to an item? Also, not all CSS is class based - do you also want to consider other aspects of layout when trimming CSS. That could get quite complex, quite fast.

Comment: You as the developer who potentially wrote and knows the tech and site should be able to accomplish the task you want by not including the css that isn't needed.  Also, remember those files get cached locally so once the user downloads them they are already on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, so give me a chance in terms of criticism that I'm sure I will receive for this answer.

This is exactly what minification is used for, having said that I would also incorporate this; if I was trying to achieve this I would be more inclined to make separate style sheets for that many classes (classes that are likely to be used together are on the same sheet).

This means you can load in a style sheet per page that contains the classes you need without loading in the whole sheet.

(essentially split your 230 classes into multiple style sheets according to what classes you need to use together).

EDIT: Just want to point out, a style-sheet's loading times will be negligible unless it's a couple of MB in size at least.